# Using variables created by Macro.var

Tags: macros, elixir

I'm trying "templatize" some redundant code.  I can get it to generate compiler warnings about unused variables but I get "invalid quoted expressions" with I try to use those same variables.

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmacro __using__(variables) do
    quote do 
      def mapify(unquote(Enum.map(variables, &Macro.var(&1, nil))) do
         # will yield compiler warnings about unused variables
         %{}

         # invalid quoted expression
         unquote(Enum.map(variables, &{&1, Macro.var(&1, nil)}) |> Map.new)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
defmodule X do
  use Foo, [:alpha, :bravo, :charlie]
end
```

*How can I generate this?*

```
defmodule X do
  def mapify(alpha, bravo, charlie) do
    %{alpha: alpha, bravo: bravo, charlie: charlie}
  end
end
```

Elixir 1.7.3, Erlang 21.0

**EDIT:**

This will generate a functionally correct version but I'm worried about the Enum.zip running on every call...

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmacro __using__(variables) do
    vars = Enum.map(variables, &Macro.var(&1, nil))
    result = quote do 
      def mapify(unquote(vars)) do
         Enum.zip(unquote(variables), unquote(vars)) |> Map.new
      end
    end

    IO.puts("Macro generated:\n#{result |> Macro.to_string}")
    result
  end
end
```

generated:

```
def(mapify([alpha, bravo, charlie])) do
  Enum.zip([:alpha, :bravo, :charlie], [alpha, bravo, charlie]) |> Map.new() 
end
```

**EDIT:**

Going with this unless someone can figure out the original query:

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmacro __using__(variables) do
    vars = Enum.map(variables, &Macro.var(&1, nil))
    pairs = Enum.map(variables, &{&1, Macro.var(&1, nil)}) 
    result = quote do 
      def mapify(unquote(vars)) do
         unquote(pairs) |> Map.new
      end
    end

    IO.puts("Macro generated:\n#{result |> Macro.to_string}")
    result
  end
end
```

Macro generated:

```
def(mapify([alpha, bravo, charlie])) do
  [alpha: alpha, bravo: bravo, charlie: charlie] |> Map.new()
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer [provided by José](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/8283#issuecomment-430119049):

> A map is not a quoted expression, it is a value. Every time you have a value, you need to make sure you `Macro.escape/1` it so it becomes a AST:
>
> ```rb
> quote do
>   def foo(unquote(args)) do
>     [unquote(map_kw), unquote(Macro.escape(map))]
>   end
> end
> ```

That said, all you need is:

```rb
- unquote(pairs) |> Map.new
+ unquote(Macro.escape(pairs))
```

---

*My original answer, that still works because it builds an AST of map manually:*

Well, I was not able to find less hacky way, and I don’t understand why keyword differs from map here, but here you go:

```rb
defmodule Foo do
  defmacro __using__(variables) do
    # allow sigil as input
    variables = Macro.expand(variables, __ENV__)

    vars = Enum.map(variables, &Macro.var(&1, nil))
    kw = for var <- variables, do: {var, Macro.var(var, nil)}
    # ⇓⇓⇓⇓ HERE ⇓⇓⇓⇓
    map = {:%{}, [], kw}

    result =
      quote do
        def mapify(unquote(vars)) do
          unquote(map)
        end
      end

    IO.puts("Macro generated:\n#{result |> Macro.to_string}")
    result
  end
end
defmodule Test, do: use Foo, ~w|alpha bravo charlie|a
```

Please note I have corrected another issue (in the very first line) for this macro to accept sigil for atom list.

Also, you might want to use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.unquote_splicing/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#unquote_splicing/1) instead of `unquote` in `def mapify(unquote_splicing(vars))` to make it accept a list of arguments.

---

*Sidenote:* I doubt I understand the purpose of this particular macro. Maybe generic-purpose sigil would suit your needs better. Or, just stay with generic Elixir syntax, it’s succinct enough.

Please read this post by [Andrea](https://andrealeopardi.com/posts/a-story-of-regret-and-retiring-a-library-from-hex/) for pros and contras (it contains a link to the repo with `~m` short maps sigil history.)

Comment: The `map=` line was what was tripping me up in my implementation (had to alter the example to avoid leaking code that isn't mine).  I didn't need the sigil, however.  `kw = zip(variables, map(variables, &Macro.var(&1, nil)))` worked for the example.

Comment: You didn’t need a sigil yesterday, but tomorrow you might get tired of typing `[:foo, :bar, :baz]` and stick to `~w|foo bar baz|a` as many do. It’s a matter of a good habit to support respective sigils where lists are allowed. The `map=` line is a hack and the more I think about it the more I am convinced it’s a bug in Elixir macro implementation. I will probably submit it.